# premiere cc: LINK audio and video tracks greyed out

Tags: premiere, audio, adobe, cc

I have multiple audio clips and want to link them to a video clip. I first unlinked the camera audio from the video, then selected the video clips, the cam audio and the external recorded audio clips. Now the context menu entry "LINK" is greyed out. I can only relink the original audio clips to the video clip. This doesn't make any sense to me. To group clips doesn't help me either, because if I intercut the group, all parts are grouped together.

[image]

Any solutions for this?

Comment: Okay, so here is the answer: as you can see above, the clips on A1 and A3 are mono, the clip on A3 is stereo. This has nothing to do with the tracks, all three tracks are "standard", so they allow to carry stereo and mono clips. After setting the clip on A3 to mono in the project panel, and adding it anew to the A3 track, it finally works. Now with ALL three clips in mono, I now can link them together with the video clip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three ways to put things together in Premiere Pro: linking, grouping, and nesting.  Linking is the lowest-level, assigning audio tracks to a single video clip.  You cannot link two video clips together, regardless of how much audio they may want to share.

Grouping allows you to treat multiple clips of audio and video as part of the same group for selection, moving, trimming, etc.  If you have a bunch of related clips (video and audio) which you want to behave as a unit, but whose relationships you still want to be able to see, use grouping.

Nesting creates a new sequence with all the audio and video clips you want to behave as if it's just a single entity.  You can change the relationships (and of course edit) within that entity, but to do so you have to open up that sequence on its own timeline.

You probably want to use either grouping or nesting, not linking for this case.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for clarifying the underlying concepts! For what I wanted to do _linking_ still seems the way to go. I allready found the answer why it didn't work here at first place - see my comment above.